# using the "freehand" construction tool

Tags: arcmap, digitizing

I am drawing hydro features with the freehand tool. Does anyone know how to delete vertices (i.e. back up) in ArcMap 10 while drawing with freehand in the construction tools? I was just curious if there was a way to do this without having to go ahead and complete the polygon and then go back and edit the vertices post completion. Thanks!

Comment: Many Editing Shortcuts (can customise too) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000011000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently use ctrl-z (Undo) to delete the last few vertices, which isn't clearly identified in the shortcut list.  That should let you 'back up' a few steps.

Comment: in Edit Tool mode >Hold down D< Delete the vertex you click. Hold down D and drag to delete multiple vertices.

Comment: That's a good one too - I really like using undo because you don't have to click anywhere.  If you just screw up and click in totally the wrong spot you can just hit ctrl-z and carry on.

Comment: yeah no ctrl-z deletes the whole feature. What I am trying to do is while using the freehand tool in stream mode, delete the previous vertex or vertices. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I've been messing around a little with the stream mode and set my stream "grouping" and "tolerance" to where they are a spaced out enough to go back and right click on the previous vertex and delete it that way.

Comment: just realized that **ctrl-z does in fact work** in stream mode. Thanks!